# NSMutableArray - App runs in simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, nsmutablearray, device, sigabrt

My app runs fine in the simulator, but when running on the device, it terminates with SIGABRT. I have narrowed it down to the following code:

```
- (void)loadImage {
int imageNumber = currentImageNumber;
// check to see if the image has already been downloaded.
// if not, get it and add it to an array
if ([imageData count] < totalNumberOfImages && (imageNumber + 1) > [imageData count]) {
    NSString *urlString = [[mainMenuItem.imageDetails objectAtIndex: imageNumber] objectForKey: @"url"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
    [imageData addObject: image];
}

// set the image from the array
self.imageOnScreen = [imageData objectAtIndex: imageNumber];
```

}

It is the [imageData addObject:image]; message that generates the crash, with the following console output:

```
2010-09-17 00:03:03.005 PilotsMate[17426:5e03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x313f4fd3 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3302f8a5 objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x31377f99 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 472
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x31377da7 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 34
    4   PilotsMate                          0x00007c5d -[WeatherDetailViewController loadImage] + 300
    5   PilotsMate                          0x00007eb1 -[WeatherDetailViewController displayPicture:] + 232
    6   Foundation                          0x33265c9d -[NSThread main] + 44
    7   Foundation                          0x332ea9e1 __NSThread__main__ + 972
    8   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x3527598d _pthread_start + 248
    9   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x3526b0ec thread_assign_default + 4294967295
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
kill
```

What is causing this, since there are no issues in the simulator? I'm very puzzled and would appreciate your input. All I am doing is initialising an NSMutableArray in viewDidLoad and then adding an object to the array. If I clean the targets, there is no change to what happens. Weird, because this part of the app ran fine a few days ago and I've not modified this implementation file at all (nor have I updated to the newest iOS 4.1 yet, so there is no change to the OS or Xcode version either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you pasted says it all:

```
[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0
```

The `image` object is `nil`. Why is it `nil`? Set a breakpoint in Xcode while running it in the Simulator and figure out which line above it in the culprit.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I misread what that said as I had an issue accidentally trying to query a nil array the other day. I get the following error:
PilotsMate(17524,0x3e9097c8) malloc: purgeable zone does not support guard pages
2010-09-17 00:27:11.768 PilotsMate[17524:5f03] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x19fe00 {NSURL=http://image.weather.com/images/sat/uksat_600x405.jpg}

Comment: If you see Jon Rodriguez's answer, he's probably on the right track. I think 256 is a networking error. Likely the simulator can't access the URL for some reason. Do you have a firewall or proxy set up on your machine? Can you access that URL from Safari on the same machine running Xcode?

Comment: That's why I now know what the error is. It runs fine in the simulator but the iPhone causes the problem when running from the device. It's connected to the same wireless router as the macbook. I can access the image from the macbook safari, but not from the iPhone I have discovered. Why would this be?

Comment: Check the wireless connection - it had picked up a neighbours connection. Don't I feel like a muppet!!!

Comment: All us programmers feel like muppets from time to time. This was just your turn. :)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Shaggy Frog's answer, I think the most likely reason for image to be nil is if there is a problem reading from the URL.  Try using [dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:) and checking the outputted error to see what happened.